# AngularJs Dialog has Option to Select parent Element Reference - Seems Angular 2+ Doesn't

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, modal-dialog, overlay

The **angularjs** has option to supply parent element on which the pop-up or dialog to be opened.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog

```
   $mdDialog.alert()
     .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#popupContainer')))
     .clickOutsideToClose(true)
```

Seems the same is not available easily on angular.
Does anyone able to crack this or have workaround for anular 8+?

Requirement is:
We would like to open the popup only on the selective area of entire window/document.
Say we have header, Left Menu, Body and footer. We would like to open dialog only on the area of body without hiding/cdk-backdrop header, menu and footers.

Comment: Do you want to implement this inside angular 2.0+ version and onwards ?

Comment: Hopefully, it is ok to have around 8+;
The problem is we have to calculate px ourselves to position, if angular carry the above feature it will be a great plus and many people can use for their product or project. Also i hope you will take care of CDK overlay only for a given class of div as well (document.querySelector). AngularJS neatly does that at the moment and that is beautiful implementation.

Comment: So basically you want to open angular-dialog mat-dialog inside body only.

Comment: that's right GaurangDhorda, on a selected parent element reference.

Comment: I have found a concreate solution for you :) Once you online here comment me here. :)

Comment: Hi Gaurang, i am here. not sure if there is 1 to 1 chat in stack overflow.

Comment: is your design responsive ? Means in smaller screen size you need to only display main-body part only.

Comment: if you are meaning mobile view rendering with media query, yes; We consider as mobile if width is lessor to 600px width; In that case we had to display only body.

Comment: https://angular-51r6tx.stackblitz.io/ is this right for you ?

Comment: Kind of, still wondering how this is centered to a div? As of now i believe opening down to the button like menu option. I can see if this works for us.

Comment: Yes sure, let you check it at your side , or I have another way to do . Are you from which country ?

Comment: India bangalore - Will check this and let you know in few days. What we wondered is the overlay and the window and sub scroll action on this cdk-overlays. Will have to study yours deeply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232705/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-saravanan-thangavel).